# How to set up rig so it automatically switches between object mode and pose mode?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode, object-mode

The title pretty much says it all, I remember on one .blend file I tried, it was set so that depending on what rig/object you clicked, it would switch accordingly. How would you do this?

Example:

.blend I found online:
[image: Rig i found online]

My .blend

[image: my .blend]

As you can see, in mine I cannot switch between rig <> object or rig <> rig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Edit Menu & disable Lock Object Modes.

[image: Lock Object Modes]